# Why does read() block indefinitely when reading a buffer

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm new to socket programming and wanted to try something simple. This program can manipulate settings on my tv. All messages are 24 bytes.  There may be one or more messages returned.  I cannot figure out a good solution to get all of the messages without read() blocking on me.
What is below would be what I hoped to be a simple solution.  It seems to work in a lot of example code I have found.  However, what happens is after the first loop it seems to just block on the read() operation infinitely.  If I remove the loop and just put multiple reads, the same thing happens.  As long as I don't try to read more information that is sent, I'm ok.

I did try a couple of other things like turning off blocking, and adding a timer.  neither worked.  At this point I can live with a couple seconds of blocking.  I just want the program to exit normally after the read.

adding output for a power_on command.  It correctly outputs the two lines it should then blocks indefinitely.

```
Dans-MBP:~ mreff555$ ./tvthing 
24: *SAPOWR0000000000000000

24: *SNPOWR0000000000000001
```

code below:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define PORT 20060

#define POWER_ON        "*SCPOWR0000000000000001\n"
#define POWER_OFF       "*SCPOWR0000000000000000\n"
#define POWER_STATUS    "*SEPOWR################\n"
#define POWER_TOGGLE    "*STPOWR################\n"

int main(int argc, char const * argv[])
{
  struct sockaddr_in tvAddress;
  struct hostent *host = gethostbyname("192.168.1.128");
  memset(&tvAddress, 0,  sizeof(tvAddress));
  tvAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
  tvAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  tvAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = ((struct in_addr*)(host->h_addr))->s_addr;
  tvAddress.sin_port = htons(PORT);

  char sendBuffer[24] = {0};
  char recBuffer[24] = {0};

  int socket_fd;

  if((socket_fd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
  {
    perror("socket failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else
  {
    if(connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&tvAddress, sizeof(struct sockaddr)))
    {
      perror("connection failed failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   memcpy(&sendBuffer, &POWER_STATUS, sizeof(sendBuffer));
   write(socket_fd, sendBuffer, strlen(sendBuffer));

   int ret;
   while((ret = read(socket_fd, recBuffer, sizeof(recBuffer)) > 0))
   {
     printf("%d: %s\n", ret, recBuffer);
   }

   close(socket_fd); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208776/discussion-on-question-by-mreff555-why-does-read-block-indefinitely-when-readi).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it turns out, select is designed exactly for that purpose. It checks the specified file descriptors for a specified time interval, and if successful repeats the process.  Tweaking the time interval minimizes the blocking while allowing enough time for additional messages to come in.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

#define PORT 20060

#define POWER_ON        "*SCPOWR0000000000000001\n"
#define POWER_OFF       "*SCPOWR0000000000000000\n"
#define POWER_STATUS    "*SEPOWR################\n"
#define POWER_TOGGLE    "*STPOWR################\n"

int main(int argc, char const * argv[])
{
  struct sockaddr_in tvAddress;
  struct hostent *host = gethostbyname("192.168.1.128");
  memset(&tvAddress, 0,  sizeof(tvAddress));
  tvAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
  tvAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  tvAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = ((struct in_addr*)(host->h_addr))->s_addr;
  tvAddress.sin_port = htons(PORT);

  char sendBuffer[24] = {0};
  char recBuffer[24] = {0};

  int socket_fd;

  if((socket_fd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
  {
    perror("socket failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else
  {
    if(connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&tvAddress, sizeof(struct sockaddr)))
    {
      perror("connection failed failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   struct timeval tv;
   fd_set sockRead;
   int selectStatus;

   memcpy(&sendBuffer, &POWER_ON, sizeof(sendBuffer));
   write(socket_fd, sendBuffer, strlen(sendBuffer));

   do
   {
     FD_ZERO(&sockRead);
     FD_SET(socket_fd, &sockRead);
     tv.tv_sec = 2;
     tv.tv_usec = 500000;
     selectStatus = select(socket_fd + 1, &sockRead, NULL, NULL, &tv);

     switch(selectStatus)
     {
       case -1:
         perror("select()");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
         break;

       case 0:
         break;

       default:
        printf("Ready for Reading\n");
        read(socket_fd, recBuffer, sizeof(recBuffer));
        printf("%s\n", recBuffer);
     }
   }while (selectStatus > 0);

   close(socket_fd); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Well so is SO_RCVTIMEO, but read timeouts aren't a proper solution to an application protocol issue. You need to read the number of response strings appropriate to each message, which is surely specified for the device..

Comment: That is not correct.  These are not scheduled messages.  For example.  Sending the signal to power on may trigger the TV to send the current power status message if it is received.  It also may send the Action indicator as well if it is able to turn on the tv.  Those are both variable results with inconsistent processing times. You have to anticipate them, but you cannot rigidly build the system to require them.

Answer (score -1):

You need to read until your buffer is full like this:

```
unsigned readLen = 0;
unsigned totalLen = sizeof(recBuffer);

while (readLen < totalLen) {
    int ret = read(socket_fd, recBuffer + readLen, totalLen - readLen);
    if (ret > 0) {
        readLen += ret;
    } else {
        // error handling here
        break;
    }
}
```

This is needed because `read()` returns only the currently available amount of bytes which might be less than you have requested. From the corresponding [man-page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html):

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file), and the file position is advanced by this number.  It is not an error if this number is smaller than the number  of  bytes  requested; this  may  happen  for  example because fewer bytes are actually available right now (maybe because we were close to end-of-file, or because we are reading from a pipe, or from a terminal), or because read() was interrupted by a signal.

If you need to receive several responses you can put the described algorithm into a function and use it repeatedly. In any case you need to know how many responses to expect otherwise your `read()` will block because it seems that your TV's server is programmed to keep the connection open and it is client's responsibility to choose when to disconnect.

If you decide to make your application more sophisticated you can use one of the [IO Multiplexing mechanisms](https://devarea.com/linux-io-multiplexing-select-vs-poll-vs-epoll/) to make your wait for response interruptable by timer or terminal input. For example:

```
while (true) {
    pollfd fds[] = {
        { socket_fd, POLLIN, 0 },
        { STDIN_FILENO, POLLIN, 0 }
    };

    int ret = poll(fds, sizeof(fds) / sizeof(*fds), -1);
    if (ret > 0) {
        if (fds[0].revents & POLLIN) {
            readResponse(); // read and process response
        }
        if (fds[1].revents & POLLIN) {
            break; // exit on terminal input
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's many more issues than just this. You should read the comments. Also, 0 bytes read is not necessarily an error.

Comment: @S.S.Anne, the answer directly addresses OP's question, so I don't understand the DV.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted, but I pointed out some reasons that another person might have downvoted.

Comment: He stated that there may be one or more messages returned, which is is why he is issuing multiple reads. This code doesn't address that in any way.

Comment: @user207421, according to the documentation provided by the OP, all requests and responses are 24-byte long, the example above is showing how to read **one** such response since the OP is sending one request.

Comment: And receiving more than one reply, according to the OP, and he has now provided an example. And he hasn't said anything about receiving partial replies. Read the question.